# Access JQuery Object while passing array as argument

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

```
$('input-selector').somefunction([{search:function(){ funabc(@); }])
```

This code give me simple object like "{search:...}".

but

I want to get jquery Selector Object I mean `$('input-selector')`.

```
$("textarea[name='medicine_type[print_format]']").textcomplete [ { words: ['asad'] match: /\b(\w{1,})$/ search: (term, callback) -> callback $.map(that.searchAttrName(@), (word) -> if word.indexOf(term) == 0 then word else null ) return index: 1 replace: (word) -> word + ' ' }]
```

I am Passing This(@) object, in searchAttrName(), which is simple object{} not jquery object.

Comment: Where do you set `@`?

Comment: What is `somefunction`, and what does it do with the array?

Comment: Please put that in the question. There's no formatting in comments, code is really hard to read.